# Java check if file size is larger than 0

Tags: java, android, if-statement, filesize

Hi i'm trying to create an if statement that checks the size of a file here's what i have although it's not working.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file.zip");
long fileSize = file.length();
if (!(fileSize > 0));{
Toast.makeText(MainMethod.this, "Equal to 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(MainMethod.this, "Greater than 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: What does it mean for it to not be working? What would be different if it were working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of your IF statement which is causing the problem here.

Comment: Source code formatting (which Eclipse can do) would have made that obvious.

Comment: @Thilo: Assuming he is using an IDE... Don't factor out the possibility of a beginner trying to learn the language.

Comment: Well, he is making Android programs, so I'd assume that the only people not using the Eclipse SDK here are experts.

Comment: @Thilo: What I mentioned in my previous comment was just one possibility. There is also the possibility of the OP trying to learn Java by dabbling in Andriod and is new to Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ etc. Plus, I personally prefer that beginners understand to get a "feel" of their code rather than relying on IDE's for *everything*. Of course, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

There is a semicolon at the end of your if statement. Also, you can simplify the code somewhat by doing the following:

```
  if (file.length() > 0) 
  System.out.println("File Greater than 0");
else 
  System.out.println("File LessThanEqual to 0");
```

Just my opinion